# Javascript : Execute code after a self executing anonymous function is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script "selfexec.js" which does few things:

```
!function(){ A = {init : init}}()
```

I basically use this script as a plugin that can be loaded from other sites.

So, from Site B, I load this function and then want to call the method A.init but A is always coming out as undefined as its getting executed even before the anonymous function is loaded.

I tried to attach it to the window but still no luck

Anyone has better approach of doing this? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is the `!` for? You also need to wrap your function in parethises if you want it to be self invoking: `(function(){ A = {init : init}})()`

Comment: Could you please show how you load this script? Html, JS etc. Giving a good answer without knowing the context is hard.

Comment: @NicholasRobinson Usually it's an artifact of minification

Comment: @Drakes hm.. Never see that before

Comment: @NicholasRobinson usage of ! allows you NOT to wrap function into (). let's say !function(){ A = {init : init}}() is the same as if (function(){ A = {init : init}})()

Comment: You'll need to provide more context, literally. Are you trying to execute the function in different contexts to modify a var that's been declared in different places? What scope is 'A' originally in? Why do you need an immediately invoked function?

Comment: @NicholasRobinson: What others are trying to say is: it's not that you need to wrap the function in parens. It's that to execute the function immediately you need the function to be in expression context. One way to make an expression is to enclose a statement in parenthesis. You can also put the statement to the right of an `=` sign. Or you can use any math or logic operators. So `!` works just as well as `()`

Comment: @slebetman I learned something today! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

it seems like the issue is that you are trying to use A variable before it was initialized by 3rd party script. So the order is matter here: load 3rd party script before and start use it after. Also I personally like an approach with putting calls to the queue (similar approach is used even for google analitics). read about it more here

https://coderwall.com/p/2wmqhw/load-3rd-party-js-asynchronously-initialize-queue-replace-queue

so, you will need to define a way how your client should load code from your site and all methods will 100% be executed after 3rd party code was loaded and initialized.